# SQL Query: Attempting to pull the most recent with other parameters

Tags: sql-server

I work in a school system with student data in a database.  At least each year (and sometimes multiple times a year) a new row of data is created for that student which represents a new "document".  I am trying to write a query to pull the most recent row of information for that student if that row meets other criteria (e.g. it needs to be of a type 'compsped' and it needs to have a status of 'F' or 'I').  When I run the query I wrote below, it works pretty well, but it seems to be missing some data.  I think the reason it is missing some data is because it is looking first for the most recent document and THEN it is filtering out the documents that don't meet the other criteria.  Instead, I want it to first filter out the documents that don't meet the other criteria and of THAT list I want it to pull the most recent row from that list.  We are using SQL Server 20016.  Hopefully that makes sense.  Please ask questions if it doesn't.  Thanks!

```
SELECT evaluationreports1.Status, 
evaluationreports1.EvalDueDate, 
evaluationreports1.EvalRptDate, 
evaluationreports1.StudentID, 
evaluationreports1.TypeAbbrev
FROM PlansAnoka.dbo.evaluationreports evaluationreports1
WHERE evalrptdate = (select max(evalrptdate) from evaluationreports where studentid = evaluationreports1.studentid) 
AND (evaluationreports1.TypeAbbrev='CompSpEd') 
AND (evaluationreports1.Status In ('F','I'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modification to your existing query would work:

```
SELECT evaluationreports1.Status, 
evaluationreports1.EvalDueDate, 
evaluationreports1.EvalRptDate, 
evaluationreports1.StudentID, 
evaluationreports1.TypeAbbrev
FROM PlansAnoka.dbo.evaluationreports evaluationreports1
WHERE evalrptdate = (
  select max(evalrptdate) 
  from evaluationreports i 
  where i.studentid = evaluationreports1.studentid 
  and i.TypeAbbrev='CompSpEd'
  and i.Status In ('F','I')
  )
```

---

Another way of doing this would be to use **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**

[**`with common_table_expression as ()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**

```
with cte as (
  select  *
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by studentid 
              order by evalrptdate desc
            )
    from PlansAnokt.dbo.evaluationreports t
    where t.TypeAbbrev='CompSpEd'
      and t.Status in ('F','I')
)
select *
  from cte
  where rn = 1
```

or without the `cte`

```
select *
  from (
    select  *
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by studentid 
              order by evalrptdate desc
            )
    from PlansAnokt.dbo.evaluationreports t
    where t.TypeAbbrev='CompSpEd'
      and t.Status in ('F','I')
      ) as cte
  where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your first suggestion just as written and I'm getting an "incorrect syntax near ')' error.  I'm going to keep looking to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @bosstone75 Corrected the error for the first query. Give it a shot now.

Comment: @SqlZim Good on ya.  I spent too much time prettying up the CTE in my editor and you beat me to it :-) Haha! Upvoted.

Comment: Excellent.  The first option worked for me and I can wrap my head around it.  I'm new to SQL and I haven't experienced Row Number yet so that was a little beyond me!  Thanks for the help!